# How do you pause before fading an element out using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I would like to flash a success message on my page.

I am using the jQuery `fadeOut` method to fade and then remove the element. I can increase the duration to make it last longer, however this looks strange.

What I would like to happen is have the element be displayed for five seconds, then fade quickly, and finally be removed.

How can you animate this using jQuery?

Comment: are 'hacks' still needed with jQuery 1.3.1 or above? this question is a few months old so hoping there's a better way now?

Comment: @Simon - as of 1.4, no - see my answer below.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The new `delay()` function in jQuery 1.4 should do the trick.

```
$('#foo').fadeIn(200).delay(5000).fadeOut(200).remove();
```

Answer (score 11):

use `setTimeout(function(){$elem.hide();}, 5000);`

Where `$elem` is the element you wish to hide, and `5000` is the delay in milliseconds. You can actually use any function within the call to `setTimeout()`, that code just defines a small anonymous function for simplicity.

Answer (score 8):

While @John Sheehan's approach works, you run into the [jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut ClearType glitch](http://blog.bmn.name/2008/03/jquery-fadeinfadeout-ie-cleartype-glitch/) in IE7. Personally, I'd opt for @John Millikin's `setTimeout()` approach, but if you're set on a pure jQuery approach, better to trigger an animation on a non-opacity property, such as a margin.

```
var left = parseInt($('#element').css('marginLeft'));
$('#element')
    .animate({ marginLeft: left ? left : 0 }, 5000)
    .fadeOut('fast');
```

You can be a bit cleaner if you know your margin to be a fixed value:

```
$('#element')
    .animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, 5000)
    .fadeOut('fast');
```

**EDIT**: It looks like the [jQuery FxQueues plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fxqueues) does just what you need:

```
$('#element').fadeOut({
    speed: 'fast',
    preDelay: 5000
});
```

Answer (score 6):

For a pure jQuery approach, you can do

```
$("#element").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut();
```

It's a hack, but it does the job

Answer (score 4):

```
var $msg = $('#msg-container-id');
$msg.fadeIn(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $msg.fadeOut(function(){
      $msg.remove();
    });
  },5000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on from dansays' comment, the following seems to work perfectly well:

`$('#thing') .animate({dummy:1}, 2000)
            .animate({ etc ... });`

Answer (score 1):

dansays's answer just doesn't work for me. For some reason, `remove()` runs immediately and the div disappears before any animations happen.

The following works, however (by omitting the `remove()` method):

```
$('#foo').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
```

I don't mind if there are hidden DIVs on the page (there shouldn't be more than a few anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Update for 1.6.2

Nathan Long's answer will cause the element to pop off without obeying delay or `fadeOut`.

This works:

```
$('#foo').delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
```