# Jquery: Div Fade in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to make a div fade in evey 30sec and out after 30sec

```
setInterval(function(){$('#myDiv').toggle();}, 300);
$("#popupboxdis").fadeIn("fast");
$("#popupboxdis").fadeOut("fast");
```

Comment: You have been trying... Ok? And where the problem is?

Comment: The first line should do it. What are the other lines for?

Comment: Exact Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117273/show-and-hide-div-every-1min

Comment: setInterval(function(){$('#myDiv').toggle();}, 300); -- The 300 you've put is in MilliSeconds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254/how-do-you-pause-before-fading-an-element-out-using-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setInterval time is in milliseconds:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#myDiv').toggle('normal');
}, 30000);
```

Notice the extra `0`s. As it is right now it will try to toggle the element every 300 milliseconds or .3 seconds which is probably resulting in some wacky behavior. Also, the code above should do what you described, I am not sure where the other 2 lines come into play...

Also note that without a time string ('slow', 'normal', 'fast') or a time in ms (1000, 2000) as an argument, [`toggle`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) will simply hide and show the elements without the fading animation you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to toggle between fadeOut and fadeIn.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#myDiv').toggle(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    });
}, 30000);
```

Comment: toggle('fast') achieves this... why complicate it?

Comment: toggle("fast") iterates between show/hide and not fideIn/fideOut

Comment: Depends on the effect you're looking for. Toggle chooses how to fade in / fade out. fadeIn/fadeOut has more control.

Comment: Yeah, ScottE, I see that. toggle('fast') seems to do a slideDown/fade mix, which is odd.